# How does Traversable use the fact that it subclasses both Foldable and Functor?

Tags: haskell, functor, traversable, foldable

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where

    traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
    traverse g = sequenceA . fmap g

    sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
    sequenceA = traverse id
```

How does `Traversable` use the fact that it subclasses both `Foldable` and `Functor`?

`t` being a traversable type implies `t` is also a functor type and a foldable type.

I see that the fact that `t` is a functor type, i.e. `fmap` , is used  in `traverse`.

Is the fact that `t` is a foldable type used somewhere?

Does `traverse` use the fact that `t` is a foldable type?

Which fact does `sequenceA` use: `t` being a functor type, `t` being a foldable type, or both?

Can we define a class which is a subclass of `Functor` only and has both `traverse` and `sequenceA` functions defined in the same way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The `Foldable` instance is not used. Nevertheless, it is fine to demand `Foldable`, since if we can `traverse` a thing, then we can `foldMap` it:

```
foldMapDefault :: (Traversable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldMapDefault f = fst . traverse (\a -> (f a, ()))
```

The basic idea here is to use the standard writer monad; since the bind operation for the writer uses `mappend` to combine the "written" part -- here, the `f a` values -- `traverse` will `mappend` together just the right things. (It will also build up a `t ()` that we don't actually care about; throwing away that part is the job of `fst`.)

For simplicity and self-containment, I've used the writer monad, but the true implementation uses the slightly mind-bending `Const` applicative to avoid building (and then throwing away) the uninteresting `t ()` value. You may see the documentation of `foldMapDefault` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:foldMapDefault) and its implementation [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#foldMapDefault).

Comment: What makes `Const` too magical? Yeah, the implementation of `foldMapDefault` is full of coercion magic, but that's not essential.

Comment: @dfeuer My judgment, based on this user's other questions, is that a good answer for this user should introduce one and only one new idea at a time. Turning a traversal into a fold is already that one idea. I can only hope that the writer monad was not a second idea already, let alone the less complicated but also less popular `Const` applicative.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Traversable), class `Traversable` is a `Functor` and a `Foldable`, and must satisfy the laws:

And `Foldable` see more [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Foldable). That means that it can be folded (foldMap, foldr, foldl...)

`traverse` function must satisfy the laws:

- naturality:

  t . traverse f = traverse (t . f) for every applicative transformation t
- identity

  traverse Identity = Identity
- composition

  traverse (Compose . fmap g . f) = Compose . fmap (traverse g) . traverse f

and sequenceA:

- naturality

  t . sequenceA = sequenceA . fmap t for every applicative transformation t
- identity

  sequenceA . fmap Identity = Identity
- composition

  sequenceA . fmap Compose = Compose . fmap sequenceA . sequenceA

> Which fact does sequenceA use: t being a Functor type, t being a Foldable type, or both?

`Traversable`, as its definition says (and the laws quoted above):

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
```

is both, a `Functor` and a Foldable, by the laws it has to obey, it is not only a `Functor`, is more specific than a `Functor` (but still a Functor because satisfies the laws of Functor and can use the functions of its typeclass interface), and even more specific than `Foldable`, hence powerful, less general, with more constraints.

And what's the fact? The definition, but why the designer of `Traversable` choose those two? Because is useful, as you can see in @Daniel Wagner answer. Other examples:

```
instance Traversable [] where
    traverse f = List.foldr cons_f (pure [])
      where cons_f x ys = liftA2 (:) (f x) ys
```

this one uses `foldr`

```
instance Foldable [] where
    elem    = List.elem
    foldl   = List.foldl
    foldl'  = List.foldl'
    foldl1  = List.foldl1
    foldr   = List.foldr
    foldr1  = List.foldr1
    length  = List.length
    maximum = List.maximum
    minimum = List.minimum
    null    = List.null
    product = List.product
    sum     = List.sum
    toList  = id
```

So, `Traverse` is a `Functor` and a `Foldable` so you could use the functions of its interface when needed. (as in the example, is just an example not a justification of why the designer chooses to define `Traversable` with `Functor` and `Foldable`), is because is useful.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main reasons for subclassing in general:

1. You need the class to make your definition work, or at least it makes the implementation so much more clear that it doesn't really make sense to leave it out. This is the case here for `Functor`.
2. You can derive the other class for free from the parts you already have for your main definition, so you may as well declare it.  This is the case here for `Foldable`.

Comment: There are definitely other reasons for superclasses. `Num` is a superclass of `Integral` because it doesn't make sense for something to be integral if it's not a number. `Semigroup` is (now) a superclass of `Monoid` because a monoid is a semigroup with an identity element (mathematically).

Comment: @dfeuer The semigroup-monoid relation arguably falls under point (2) here.

Comment: @DanielWagner, that's purely a historical accident.